# Swipe from corners and edges of android phone

Tags: android, swipe, touch-event, listeners

I have to implement swipe listeners, so that it can listen to the swipes whether from corner or edge of android device. I have implemented override method onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) to get edge flags. But value of edge flag is always set to zero. My question is how to listen to swipes that are from corner or edge of device.

Thanks in advance.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && (event.getEdgeFlags() == MotionEvent.EDGE_RIGHT) || event.getEdgeFlags() == MotionEvent.EDGE_LEFT) {
            mOverlayLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else if (event.getFlags() == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) {
            mOverlayLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create OnSwipeTouchListener.java

```
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
       import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
       import android.view.MotionEvent;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

   public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

   private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MyActivity.this) {
public void onSwipeTop() {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void onSwipeRight() {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void onSwipeLeft() {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void onSwipeBottom() {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

});

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938787/7199177

Comment: By using this, entire screen responds to this. But, I have to detect swipes only from corners of the display as in apps EasySwipe, Lazyswipe etc..,

Comment: okay okay sorry my bad, edge mask hmmm
can you try to use onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) *